# Question closed? Why?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I've this question at stackoverflow and at serverfault: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579273/html5-video-browser-performance and here https://serverfault.com/questions/388971/html5-video-browser-performance#comment402270_388971 and I got insulted and downvoted and then closed? I'm just curious. Why this downvotes? And why is this question closed at stackoverflow? It's about html5 and I got my question about server? Why isn't this a programming question? Didn't I have enough reputation to ask this?

Comment: First off, [Stack Overflow is not cross-posting friendly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129890/140505). Second - the question lacks in details. You have done 0 research and have provided no information about your setup, meaning no one can answer the question. See [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505) as well.

Comment: And to forestall your next question here - [Votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Oded: Nobody is cross-posting friendly that's because I've wrote this in my question serverfault in the first sentence? Is this already an offense? I mean I have some reputations and I got closed in like a minute?

Comment: Protip: Reputation counts for squat. You could have 100k rep for all I care, and if you ask a bad question, the community will close it.

Comment: Your questions got closed and downvoted because they are not good questions and are either much too broad in nature or off-topic to the sites you have posted them on. You should read the FAQ of the sites you post on before asking questions on them.

Comment: @yoda: Do you think? 100k is always intimidating. By the way don't you think that are much guys who can sell themself here? I've answered a lot of programming question.

Comment: As a 100k user on SO I can tell you that I _expect_ a bad post of mine (question _or_ answer) to be downvoted to oblivion. And believe me, they get downvoted more so when the rep is noticed.

Comment: @Oded: Hmm. I'm not enjoying programming that much but I've experience with so. You can read my reputation. Mostly I've answered very complicated things and not easy to understand. Now my question was something about HTML5 and video and browser and server so nothing very complicated but I got downvoted and closed too. And then the throw in the money thing. That's is expensive? I answere also for free here on so???

Comment: @Oded: Here is also a question of me that get frequently downvoted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499022/how-many-edges-can-i-store-in-a-vertex? It's legit question now I get a downvote today maybe because I asked this question on meta???

Comment: @Oded: And here is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594009/generating-all-triples-from-a-graph.

Comment: You seem to consistently miss the issue - in all these questions, you have not shown what you have tried nor explained where _exactly_ you are stuck. They all read as requests for other to do the work for you. Did you ever read [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet?

Comment: @Oded: Maybe you can teach me some about asking better questions but I can remember a guy here he has 80k votes in about 1-2 month. His name was Genesis. What I would say is that I don't have any experience with html5 and video and serving much video but I need to learn it fast. Sometimes what you asked is like being a slave??? I don't want to be part of a group and ended as slave?? But my question get 2x times closed in like a minute?? And I'm not a nobody here on this site.

Comment: I gave you a link to a very good article by Jon Skeet about asking questions. Read that.

Comment: The answer to your question is multicast

Comment: @Jitamaro Are you comparing yourself to genesis?  That may not be the best course of action given the fact that he basically fell off the earth after trying to run as a moderator.

Comment: @JNK: I want to say that this site is about votes, too, and yes I did a mistake and didn't vote him. He got 80k in a couple of month and that's an achievement. Maybe the site is more funny with him when he is a mod. But honestly I don't know what your question has to do with my question? If you know about html5 and video and server you can actually help me and help others to stop this discussion and shed some light on this complicate question on how to serve as much video to as much people with the least effort possible?

Comment: @Jitamaro: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. It's no different than someone asking "How do I set up an e-Commerce website?" and other such things. SO deals with *specific* problems, not general tasks. Thus, your question was downvoted and closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, I'm not agree with you because video and html5 and server and performance is already a good question. But what do you want to know? You see the downvotes? That's explains many things.

Comment: @Jitamaro: "video and html5 and server and performance is already a good question." Yes, you can ask a question about each of them individually. Or all of them at once. But when your question is asking for a large task like that, it's just too general purpose to be handled here.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I want to say a good programmer can answer this. Someone who has done this before. I'm not asking unexperience guy. And html5 and the video tag is something that has been discussed in the internet. It's a huge discussion about flash and html5. Don't sell me crap and try to take me or ppl serious I've the right to defend myself and downvote anybody I want and to refuse answering questions. That's a fact.

Comment: @Jitamaro: You do not have the right to ask *any* question about video or HTML5 or whatever. You must ask questions that are on-topic and sufficiently specific. Your question was not, and therefore it was closed. **End of story**. "I want to say a good programmer can answer this." You can want whatever you want; that will not make them true. We do not allow these kinds of questions on Stack Exchange sites. You can either accept that fact or continue arguing. But that fact will remain a fact.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, sure. When you agree with your others? That's why I'm asking it here. But look I've already my answer. It's one guy here at meta. Funny isn't it?

Comment: @Jitmaro erm, no; it's not funny. It's incomprehensible.

Answer (score 9):

The FAQs on both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/faq#dontask) contain these two paragraphs:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

If you're putting minimal effort into asking a question you expect someone else to spend hours or even days answering, you're showing some major disrespect for the folks you're directing the question at.

There are many people who dedicate their entire work day, every day, to answering the question you posed - and you expect them to write a book on it because you can't be bothered to do a bit of research on your own or even describe in detail what you're trying to accomplish?

I'm sorry, but that is completely unreasonable. Take a bit of time to think about the problem you're trying to solve before throwing it in someone else's lap, and when you do ask, have the decency to share with them first the details of what you're hoping to accomplish, the constraints you must work within, what you've already learned, and where you got stuck.

[Stack Exchange helps folks who help themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17494/im-new-to-stackoverflow-what-should-i-consider-before-asking-questions/17502#17502)...